# Way to execute a shell script by event

Tags: shell-script, centos, events

Is there a way to trigger a shell script by event not by time (cron)? For example, when the disk is full it will run a shell script to remove old logs.

Like in windows, task scheduler triggered on an event.

Comment: I don't think Linux support such notify, but you can periodically check filesystem  space usage then delete your old log. Or simply use log system which automatically delete old logs when insert new log fail

Answer (score 1):

If the events are being notified to DBUS you can use dbus-monitor to script off system events. You will have to research the documentation to see if what you want to script is posting events to DBUS to use this approach.

See here for more on DBUS: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus/

Another approach that will work when DBUS is unavailable is to write your own daemon to sit the backdrop and periodically check the events you are looking for. I for instance have my own low-disk-space daemon that I run on my system that will change my shell prompt to alert me to the condition.

Here is a snippet from it, to give you an idea:

```
declare LOWDISK='\033[38;05;160mLOWDISK\033[00m' ## Display in RED. 
declare SLEEPFREQ=60 ## Check every 60 seconds 
declare CHECKFILE=/tmp/__lowdisk__alerts__ 
declare LOWDISKFS=/tmp/__lowfs_diskspace__ 

  ### Daemonized 
if [[ "${1}" =~ ^-d ]]; then 
 if ps -ef|awk -vPID=$$ '{if($2 !~ PID)print}'|grep -q -- '[l]owdiskspace_monitor.bsh -d'; then 
  echo "*** Warning: lowdiskspace_monitor.bsh - ALREADY STARTED, skipping.. "   
 else 
  while :; do 
    ## Add your monitored disks here. 
   df -h / /mnt/adata1 /mnt/adata2 /mnt/pny1 /mnt/pny2 /mnt/samsung1 /mnt/samsung2 /mnt/samsung31 /mnt/samsung32 /mnt/seagate1 /mnt/seagate2 /mnt/seagate21 /mnt/seagate22 /mnt/mushkin1 /mnt/mushkin2 /var/host/media/removable/ELEMENT2_EXT4 /var/host/media/removable/Elements/ /var/host/media/removable/Elements_Ntfs2 /var/host/media/removable/ELEMENT_EXT4 2>"${DISCARD_DEV}" | uniq > "${CHECKFILE}" 
      ## Check for at least a GIG ("G") in each mounted monitored volume. Change this if necessary. 
   awk '{if(($4 !~ /[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*G/)&&(NR>1))print $6}' "${CHECKFILE}" > "${LOWDISKFS}"
   sleep ${SLEEPFREQ}
   rm "${LOWDISKFS}"
  done 
 fi 
fi 

[[ -s "${LOWDISKFS}" ]] && echo -en "${LOWDISK}"
```

Note: to use this you would save this to a file, make it executable and set `PROMPT_COMMAND` to it in your `.bashrc` file.

Answer (score 0):

Setup script to run periodically, but exits immediately when condition is not satisfied.

e.g.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

df "<mount point or device node or /var/log>" | 
    grep -q -e '100%' -e '9[5-9]%' || 
    exit

find /var/log -type f -name "*old logs*" -exec rm {} +
```

Comment: Why not run `df` directly on the mount point (or even `/var/log` if that's where the logs are)? Also, you may want to use `grep -F -q` (to not produce output if there is a match).

Comment: @Kusalananda Good point! And I'm using fgrep as the default Solaris installation don't support -F flag with the shipped grep command.

Comment: Sure, but the user in the question is on CentOS. If you have `/usr/xpg4/bin` early in your path on Solaris, you'd get a `grep` that does support `-F` (you should probably be using `PATH=$(/usr/xpg4/bin/getconf PATH):$PATH` (or `xpg6`) anyway; see [the `standards(7)` manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E88353_01/html/E37853/standards-7.html#REFMAN7standards-7) on Solaris).

Comment: @Kusalananda, looks like I still have to learn hard.

Comment: so you don't care about when regular users are locked out at 95% full?

Comment: @Jasen suggestion accepted.